# Saving an XML file created by Tesseract OCR as a traversable object

Tags: java, xml

My project here works upon output that comes out of a Tesseract OCR scan using hOCR format, then I read it with JDOM 2.0 and finally save it one of my own objects, which *at a later point* needs to be serializable. I have spotted one major codesmell, which is a for-loop of 5 levels deep.

An example hOCR output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name='ocr-system' content='tesseract 3.02' />
  <meta name='ocr-capabilities' content='ocr_page ocr_carea ocr_par ocr_line ocrx_word'/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class='ocr_page' id='page_1' title='image "D:\DPC2\converted\60\60.tiff"; bbox 0 0 2479 3508; ppageno 0'>
   <div class='ocr_carea' id='block_1_1' title="bbox 1690 267 2165 394">
    <p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_1' title="bbox 1690 267 2165 394">
     <span class='ocr_line' id='line_1' title="bbox 1690 267 2165 394"><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1' title="bbox 1690 267 2165 394"> </span> 
     </span>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In reality there can be many pages, areas, paragraphs, lines and words. I have only showed one of each here for simplicity and because I cannot disclose full files, also note that the content of the word shown here is " ", a string of one space.
A minor defect is that there are still some TODO comments which I need to transform to actual loggers.

First the `Traversable` structure:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <P>   The type of the parent
 * @param <C>   The type of the children
 */
public interface Traversable<P extends Traversable<?, ?>, C extends Traversable<?, ?>> {
    default public boolean hasParent() {
        return (getParent() != null);
    }

    public P getParent();

    default public boolean hasChildren() {
        return (getChildren().count() > 0);
    }

    public Stream<C> getChildren();

    public void setParent(final P parent);

    public void addChild(final C child);

    default public void addChildren(final Stream<? extends C> children) {
        children.forEach(this::addChild);
    }

    public String getId();

    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox();

    abstract public static class Void implements Traversable<Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public Void getParent() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Stream<Void> getChildren() {
            return Stream.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public void setParent(final Void parent) { }

        @Override
        public void addChild(final Void child) { }

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <P>   The type of the parent
 * @param <C>   The type of the children
 */
abstract public class AbstractTraversable<P extends Traversable<?, ?>, C extends Traversable<?, ?>> implements Traversable<P, C> {
    protected final Collection<C> children = new ArrayList<>();

    protected P parent;

    @Override
    public P getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<C> getChildren() {
        return children.stream();
    }

    @Override
    public void setParent(final P parent) {
        this.parent = Objects.requireNonNull(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void addChild(final C child) {
        this.children.add(Objects.requireNonNull(child));
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <P>   The type of the parent
 * @param <C>   The type of the children
 */
abstract public class FileElement<P extends FileElement<?, ?>, C extends FileElement<?, ?>> extends AbstractTraversable<P, C> {
    protected final String id;
    protected final BoundingBox boundingBox;

    public FileElement(final String id, final BoundingBox boundingBox) {
        this.id = Objects.requireNonNull(id);
        this.boundingBox = Objects.requireNonNull(boundingBox);
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox;
    }

    public static <E extends FileElement<?, ?>> E ofBoundingBoxElement(final Element element, final BiFunction<String, BoundingBox, E> constructor) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(element);
        Objects.requireNonNull(constructor);
        String elementId = element.getAttributeValue("id");
        String elementTitle = element.getAttributeValue("title");
        Title title = new Title(elementTitle);
        return constructor.apply(
            elementId,
            title.getBoundingBox().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No bounding box present in: " + elementTitle))
        );
    }

    abstract public static class Void extends FileElement<Void, Void> { 
        public Void(String id, BoundingBox boundingBox) {
            super(id, boundingBox);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BoundingBox {
    private final int x1;
    private final int y1;
    private final int x2;
    private final int y2;

    public BoundingBox(final int x1, final int y1, final int x2, final int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return BoundingBox.class.getSimpleName() + "(" + x1 + ", " + y1 + ", " + x2 + ", " + y2 + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.x1;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.y1;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.x2;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.y2;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final BoundingBox other = (BoundingBox) obj;
        if (this.x1 != other.x1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.y1 != other.y1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.x2 != other.x2) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.y2 != other.y2) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Title {
    private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<Title, Stream<String>>> KEYWORD_CONSUMERS = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        KEYWORD_CONSUMERS.put("bbox", new BoundingBoxConsumer());
        KEYWORD_CONSUMERS.put("image", new ImagePathConsumer());
        KEYWORD_CONSUMERS.put("ppageno", new PageNumberConsumer());
    }

    private Optional<BoundingBox> boudingBox = Optional.empty();
    private Optional<Path> imagePath = Optional.empty();
    private OptionalInt pageNumber = OptionalInt.empty();

    public Title(final String title) {
        process(Objects.requireNonNull(title));
    }

    private void process(final String title) {
        for (String part : splitTitle(title)) {
            List<String> parts = Arrays.stream(part.split(" "))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (parts.size() <= 1) {
                //TODO logger, ignoring because x
                continue;
            }
            String keyword = parts.get(0);
            if (!KEYWORD_CONSUMERS.containsKey(keyword)) {
                //TODO logger, zz not found
                continue;
            }
            KEYWORD_CONSUMERS.get(keyword).accept(this, parts.subList(1, parts.size()).stream());
        }
    }

    private List<String> splitTitle(final String input) {
        return Arrays.asList(input.split(";(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"));
    }

    private void setBoundingBox(final BoundingBox boundingBox) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(boundingBox);
        this.boudingBox = Optional.of(boundingBox);
    }

    private void setImagePath(final Path imagePath) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(imagePath);
        this.imagePath = Optional.of(imagePath);
    }

    private void setPageNumber(final int pageNumber) {
        this.pageNumber = OptionalInt.of(pageNumber);
    }

    public Optional<BoundingBox> getBoundingBox() {
        return boudingBox;
    }

    public Optional<Path> getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public OptionalInt getPageNumber() {
        return pageNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Title.class.getSimpleName() + "(" + boudingBox + ", " + imagePath + ", " + pageNumber + ")";
    }

    private static class BoundingBoxConsumer implements BiConsumer<Title, Stream<String>> {
        @Override
        public void accept(final Title title, final Stream<String> stream) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(title);
            Objects.requireNonNull(stream);
            List<Integer> arguments = stream.map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (arguments.size() != 4) {
                //TODO logger, ignoring because y
            }
            title.setBoundingBox(new BoundingBox(arguments.get(0), arguments.get(1), arguments.get(2), arguments.get(3)));
        }
    }

    private static class ImagePathConsumer implements BiConsumer<Title, Stream<String>> {
        @Override
        public void accept(final Title title, final Stream<String> stream) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(title);
            Objects.requireNonNull(stream);
            List<Path> arguments = stream.map(str -> str.replace("\"", "")).map(Paths::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (arguments.size() != 1) {
                //TODO logger, ignoring because yy
            }
            title.setImagePath(arguments.get(0));
        }
    }

    private static class PageNumberConsumer implements BiConsumer<Title, Stream<String>> {
        @Override
        public void accept(final Title title, final Stream<String> stream) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(title);
            Objects.requireNonNull(stream);
            List<Integer> arguments = stream.map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (arguments.size() != 1) {
                //TODO logger, ignoring because yyy
            }
            title.setPageNumber(arguments.get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Page extends FileElement<FileElement.Void, Area> {
    private final Path imagePath;
    private final int pageNumber;

    public static Page of(final Element element) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(element);
        String elementId = element.getAttributeValue("id");
        String elementTitle = element.getAttributeValue("title");
        Title title = new Title(elementTitle);
        return new Page(
            elementId,
            title.getBoundingBox().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No bounding box present in: " + elementTitle)),
            title.getImagePath().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No image path present in: " + elementTitle)),
            title.getPageNumber().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No page number present in: " + elementTitle))
        );
    }

    public Page(final String id, final BoundingBox boundingBox, final Path imagePath, final int pageNumber) {
        super(id, boundingBox);
        this.imagePath = Objects.requireNonNull(imagePath);
        this.pageNumber = Objects.requireNonNull(pageNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public FileElement.Void getParent() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParent(final FileElement.Void parent) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The Page element has no parent.");
    }

    public Path getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public int getPageNumber() {
        return pageNumber;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Area extends FileElement<Page, Paragraph> {
    public Area(final String id, final BoundingBox boundingBox) {
        super(id, boundingBox);
    }

    public static final Area of(final Element element) {
        return FileElement.ofBoundingBoxElement(Objects.requireNonNull(element), Area::new);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Paragraph extends FileElement<Area, Line> {
    public Paragraph(final String id, final BoundingBox boundingBox) {
        super(id, boundingBox);
    }

    public static final Paragraph of(final Element element) {
        return FileElement.ofBoundingBoxElement(Objects.requireNonNull(element), Paragraph::new);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Line extends FileElement<Paragraph, Word> {
    public Line(final String id, final BoundingBox boundingBox) {
        super(id, boundingBox);
    }

    public static final Line of(final Element element) {
        return FileElement.ofBoundingBoxElement(Objects.requireNonNull(element), Line::new);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Word extends FileElement<Line, FileElement.Void> {
    private final String content;
    private final boolean strong;

    public Word(final String id, final BoundingBox boundingBox, final String content, final boolean strong) {
        super(id, boundingBox);
        this.content = Objects.requireNonNull(content);
        this.strong = strong;
    }

    public static final Word of(final Element element) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(element);
        String elementId = element.getAttributeValue("id");
        String elementTitle = element.getAttributeValue("title");
        Title title = new Title(elementTitle);
        Element child = element.getChild("strong");
        return new Word(
            elementId,
            title.getBoundingBox().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No bounding box present in: " + elementTitle)),
            child == null ? element.getText() : child.getText(),
            child != null
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Void> getChildren() {
        return Stream.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public void addChild(final Void child) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The Word element has no children.");
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public boolean isStrong() {
        return strong;
    }
}
```

The usage:

Note that the `ScannedFile` is **not complete** (but working) yet, I will put convienience methods in there once I need them.

```
public class ScannedFile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 859948374926589L;

    private final List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(final Page page) {
        pages.add(page);
    }

    public Stream<Page> getPages() {
        return pages.stream();
    }
}
```

The actual XML reading, which has some code smell in it:

```
public static ScannedFile createScannedFileFromHOCR(final Path directory) {
    try {
        Objects.requireNonNull(directory);
        Path htmlFile = FileUtils.getSingleFileWithExtensionInDirectory(directory, Extension.HTML);
        SAXBuilder xmlBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document document = xmlBuilder.build(htmlFile.toFile());

        ScannedFile scannedFile = new ScannedFile();

        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.instance();
        System.out.println("factory = " + factory);
        XPathExpression<Element> xpePages = factory.compile(    //arguments are untyped?
            "/h:html/h:body/h:div[@class='ocr_page']",
            Filters.element(),
            null,
            Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
        );
        System.out.println("xpePages = " + xpePages);
        List<Element> pages = xpePages.evaluate(document);
        System.out.println("pages = " + pages);
        for (Element pageElement : pages) {
            Page page = Page.of(pageElement);
            XPathExpression<Element> xpeAreas = factory.compile(
                "h:div[@class='ocr_carea']",
                Filters.element(),
                null,
                Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
            );
            List<Element> areas = xpeAreas.evaluate(pageElement);
            for (Element areaElement : areas) {
                Area area = Area.of(areaElement);
                area.setParent(page);
                page.addChild(area);
                XPathExpression<Element> xpeParagraphs = factory.compile(
                    "h:p[@class='ocr_par']",
                    Filters.element(),
                    null,
                    Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
                );
                List<Element> paragraphs = xpeParagraphs.evaluate(areaElement);
                for (Element paragraphElement : paragraphs) {
                    Paragraph paragraph = Paragraph.of(paragraphElement);
                    paragraph.setParent(area);
                    area.addChild(paragraph);
                    XPathExpression<Element> xpeLines = factory.compile(
                        "h:span[@class='ocr_line']",
                        Filters.element(),
                        null,
                        Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
                    );
                    List<Element> lines = xpeLines.evaluate(paragraphElement);
                    for (Element lineElement : lines) {
                        Line line = Line.of(lineElement);
                        line.setParent(paragraph);
                        paragraph.addChild(line);
                        XPathExpression<Element> xpeWords = factory.compile(
                            "h:span[@class='ocrx_word']",
                            Filters.element(),
                            null,
                            Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
                        );
                        List<Element> words = xpeWords.evaluate(lineElement);
                        for (Element wordElement : words) {
                            Word word = Word.of(wordElement);
                            word.setParent(line);
                            line.addChild(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            scannedFile.addChild(page);
        }
        return scannedFile;

    } catch (JDOMException | IOException ex) {
        ManualUtils.moveToManual(Base.MANUAL_DIRECTORY, directory);
        throw new AutomaticExecutionFailedException(ex);
    }
}
```

An example usage:

```
ScannedFile scannedFile = OCRUtils.createScannedFileFromHOCR(path);
System.out.println("Created ScannedFile");
long elementCount = scannedFile.getPages()
        .flatMap(Page::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Area::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Paragraph::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Line::getChildren)
        .count();
List<String> wordList = scannedFile.getPages()
        .flatMap(Page::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Area::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Paragraph::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Line::getChildren)
        .map(Word::getContent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Word count: " + elementCount);
System.out.println("Word list: " + wordList);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at just the JDOM portion, there are a couple of tricks you can play.

Unfortunately, XML and streams will always be an uncomfortable mix...

The following factors in JDOM make better performance possible:

- DRY

  - XPathExpressions are threadsafe. Reuse them
  - Namespaces are threadsafe, and immutable. Reuse them
  - SAXBuilder has a relatively slow setup time (it needs to query installed XML parsers, etc.). JDOM can reuse a single configuration using a SAXEngine....

It is great that you are using relative XPath queries, and using the smaller context for them. This makes a big performance difference.

This is about as neat as I have seen this work done. It is good. I am not sure you will appreciate it if I were to suggest this is really good, and that the alternative tools/libraries (other than JDOM) would be much harder to get right.

Putting these things together, your `createScannedFileFromHOCR` method can become the following collection of statics (fully thread-safe, and better performing):

```
private static final XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.instance();
private static final Namespace XHTML = Namespace.getNamespace("h", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

private static final XPathExpression<Element> OCR_PAGE = factory.compile(    //arguments are untyped?
        "/h:html/h:body/h:div[@class='ocr_page']",
        Filters.element(),
        null,
        XHTML
    );


private static final XPathExpression<Element> OCR_CAREA = factory.compile(
        "h:div[@class='ocr_carea']",
        Filters.element(),
        null,
        XHTML
    );
private static final XPathExpression<Element> OCR_PAR = factory.compile(
        "h:p[@class='ocr_par']",
        Filters.element(),
        null,
        XHTML
    );
private static final XPathExpression<Element> OCR_LINE = factory.compile(
        "h:span[@class='ocr_line']",
        Filters.element(),
        null,
        XHTML
    );
private static final XPathExpression<Element> OCRX_WORD = factory.compile(
        "h:span[@class='ocrx_word']",
        Filters.element(),
        null,
        XHTML
    );

private static final SAXBuilder XMLBUILDER = new SAXBuilder();

private static final ThreadLocal<SAXEngine> XMLENGINE = new ThreadLocal<SAXEngine>() {
    @Override
    protected SAXEngine initialValue() {
        try {
            return XMLBUILDER.buildEngine();
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to build Engine", e);
        }
    }
};


public static ScannedFile createScannedFileFromHOCR(final Path directory) {
    try {
        Objects.requireNonNull(directory);
        Path htmlFile = FileUtils.getSingleFileWithExtensionInDirectory(directory, Extension.HTML);
        Document document = XMLENGINE.get().build(htmlFile.toFile());

        ScannedFile scannedFile = new ScannedFile();


        System.out.println("factory = " + factory);

        System.out.println("xpePages = " + OCR_PAGE);
        List<Element> pages = OCR_PAGE.evaluate(document);
        System.out.println("pages = " + pages);
        for (Element pageElement : pages) {
            Page page = Page.of(pageElement);
            List<Element> areas = OCR_CAREA.evaluate(pageElement);
            for (Element areaElement : areas) {
                Area area = Area.of(areaElement);
                area.setParent(page);
                page.addChild(area);
                List<Element> paragraphs = OCR_PAR.evaluate(areaElement);
                for (Element paragraphElement : paragraphs) {
                    Paragraph paragraph = Paragraph.of(paragraphElement);
                    paragraph.setParent(area);
                    area.addChild(paragraph);

                    List<Element> lines = OCR_LINE.evaluate(paragraphElement);
                    for (Element lineElement : lines) {
                        Line line = Line.of(lineElement);
                        line.setParent(paragraph);
                        paragraph.addChild(line);
                        List<Element> words = OCRX_WORD.evaluate(lineElement);
                        for (Element wordElement : words) {
                            Word word = Word.of(wordElement);
                            word.setParent(line);
                            line.addChild(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            scannedFile.addChild(page);
        }
        return scannedFile;

    } catch (JDOMException | IOException ex) {
        ManualUtils.moveToManual(Base.MANUAL_DIRECTORY, directory);
        throw new AutomaticExecutionFailedException(ex);
    }
}
```